# Dynamic link in nodes to hidden Quick Tabs tab

Tags: blocks

How can I make an URL that points on the same page Quick Tabs TAB. It will be good if link works without reloading page.

Comment: You want HIDE the Quick Tabs TAB or want to click the TAB when some link is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal 7, you can achieve it by using **jQuery**

- **Without reloading page** :
  Just create a Dynamic link using **ID attribute or some other attribute**, by using these attribute just click the TAB using jQuery.
- Dynamic link like

  `<a href="#" id="tab1">Link text</a>` OR

  `<a class="tab1" href="#">Link text</a>` OR

  `<a href="#" data-tab="your_selecting_tab_ID">Link text</a>`

```
  jQuery("#dynamic_link_ID").click(function(e) {//OR by using other attribute
    e.preventDefault();//it will not redirect when link is clicked
    jQuery("#quicktabs-tab_ID").click();//OR use any selector as per you requirement
  });
```